# Insert OUTPUT Insert.id to another table in multiple values insert

Tags: sql-server, sqltransaction, multiple-insert

Just for simplicity suppose I have two tables

`user table (id, email)`

`user log table (id, date)`

whatever id gets inserted in user table, same id should be inserted in user_log table also else transaction should fail.

How can I do this

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT into user(id, email) OUTPUT Inserted.id (1, 'a@x.com', 'x'), (2, 'b@x.com', 'y')  

// I also want to be able to do
INSERT into user_log(id, date) values(1, date), (2, date) 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: This might be a good candidate for implementing a trigger. Have you considered this method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can insert the output directly into the user_log table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [User] (ID, Email)
OUTPUT inserted.id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO user_log(id, date)
VALUES (1, 'a@x.com'), (2, 'b@x.com');

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a64f/1)**

---

If you need to return the ids you can just add a second `OUTPUT` clause:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [User] (ID, Email)
OUTPUT inserted.id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO user_log(id, date)
OUTPUT inserted.id                      
VALUES (1, 'a@x.com'), (2, 'b@x.com');

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the short answer. How would I return the inserted ids now?

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1 - "Double Insert" using OUTPUT

**Pros:** single statement, no hidden triggers (method 2).

**Cons:** only works in *this* statement i.e. doesn't capture all insert events

```
INSERT INTO dbo.users (id)
  OUTPUT inserted.id
  INTO user_log (id)
VALUES (9)
     , (3)
     , (7)
;
```

### Method 2 - Trigger

**Pros:** Captures *all* insert events

**Cons:** Triggers are "hidden" mechanisms

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_log_after_insert
  ON dbo.users
    AFTER INSERT
  AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.user_log (id)
  SELECT id
  FROM   inserted
  ;
END
;
```

### Method 3 - Temp Table

Included for completeness for when using older versions of SQL Server that don't support method 1

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
   id int
);

INSERT INTO #temp (id) VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO #temp (id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO #temp (id) VALUES (7);

BEGIN TRAN
  INSERT INTO dbo.users (id)
  SELECT id
  FROM   #temp
  ;
  INSERT INTO dbo.user_log (id)
  SELECT id
  FROM   #temp
  ;
COMMIT TRAN
```